# Prolog, list which identifies an item is in a current place

Tags: list, prolog, win-prolog

Im having trouble work out how to write in prolog that the chest "C" is at location "L"
This is the code i have at the moment but i think im making it too complicated and going in the wrong direction

```
    location(C, L).

    location(C, [[C,L]|_]).
    location(C, [_|T]) :-
            location(C, T, L).
```

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction into solving this.

To check it, i use this code:

```
    location(b, [(a,10), (b,6), (c,8), (d,14)]).
```

I have now changed it and have:

```
    location(C, L, P). 
    location(C, L, P) :- memberchk((C,P), L).
```

and

```
    location(b, [(a,10), (b,6), (c,8), (d,14)], P).
```

But it doesnt seem to work, what have i missed out?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
location(S, L, P) :- memberchk((S,P), L).
```

then you'll get

```
?- location(b, [(a,10), (b,6), (c,8), (d,14)], P).
P = 6.
```

Comment: I have now changed it and have: 
    location(C, L, P). 
    location(C, L, P) :- memberchk((C,P), L).

 and
    location(b, [(a,10), (b,6), (c,8), (d,14)], P).

 But it doesnt seem to work, what have i missed out?

Comment: sorry, I saw only late the win-prolog tag (I never heard of this system). Try member instead of memberchk. If that doesn't work, the answer by @iccthedral should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one, although CapelliC solution is just fine.

```
location(C, [(C,P)|_], P):-!.
location(C, [_|T], P) :- location(C, T, P).
```

Comment: @CapelliC Uh yes, that wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: Its surpose to define a predicate location(C, L) which is true if C appears exactly as a chest in the location L. Example, location(a, [(a, 10), (b, 6), (c, 8), (d, 14)]). and the result will be: yes.

Comment: Well this does exactly that, and a bit more; it unifies your third argument with the 2nd argument of the tuple when a match is found. I suggest you study Prolog a bit more, it is obvious that you're confused ATM.

Comment: Yeah ive only just started to learn it and trying some examples to build my knowledge on it.